# What is Acer Mobility Center Plug-in?

Tags: windows-vista, acer-aspire

Is it crapware and safe to uninstall or does it have some sensible function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe to uninstall just like all the other eMpowering stuff. At least I didn't find ANYTHING in them which would make them uesful. (They are just providing an easy interface for the new users). (Anyway, download the latest version of it, put it into a safe place and if you want it back for some reason, just reinstall it). (At least in my opinion..that is)

Comment: Thanks, was asking because the PC decrapifier did not uninstall this.

Comment: Such applications are not really useful (in some sense). Like... in a lot of cases, there is a need for user intervention, check what it wants to remove. Only YOU know what you need or don't need.)